# go.mod в IDE (goland) перестали работать контекстная подсказка методов

Tags: golang, mod

Есть внешний пакет ("github.com/LazarenkoA/LogrusRotate") сделал его модулем, подключил к проекту и в IDE перестали работать контекстные подсказки объектов из этого пакета и logrus (logrus входит в require go.mod) и соответственно не переходит по F12. Причем проект компилируется нормально, но вот что-то с goland, не понимает он где лежат файлы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так я сделал?

Comment: пробовал, не помогает

Comment: У меня такая же проблема, решить не удалось.

Answer (score 2):

решилось так, в настройках 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогла галка или то что я добавил каталог не знаю, но сейчас норм